# Table column width as narrow as contained data?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have three columns. The last two I want to make as narrow as the their contained data and the first column can take the rest of the width (table has 100% width).

How can you do this using CSS? Right now the columns on the right look silly with extra space. Ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just give the first column a `width` of `100%` and if necessary give the cells in all other columns a `white-space: nowrap` to avoid their content being wrapped (again, only if necessary).

E.g.

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="first">first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td></tr>
</table>
```

with

```
table { width: 100%; }
table td.first { width: 100%; }
```

Or the modern way if you don't bother about IE6 users:

```
table { width: 100%; }
table td:first-child { width: 100%; }
```

(so that you can remove `class="first"`)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I just answered this with a little different approach with [this more detailsed answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230777/how-do-i-set-the-table-cell-widths-to-minimum-except-last-column/33648895#33648895), basically:</sup>

Add the class `shrink` to columns you want to have as narrow as possible

```
<table>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
</table>
```

With this css:

```
td.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

With this you can define multiple columns to have minimum width on one line but the other's width stays dynamic (including possible line breaks).

#### Example Snippet

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
    <tr><td>first</td><td class="shrink">second</td><td class="shrink">third</td></tr>
</table>
```