# How do I set the table row heights to minimum except last row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table with rows that take up only the space they need vertically. Is there any way to do this with CSS without setting the last cell to a height of 100%?

This question is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230777/how-do-i-set-the-table-cell-widths-to-minimum-except-last-column) only in the other direction.

Currently looks like this:

```
 ---------------------------------
|                                 |
|thing 1                          |
|                                 |
 ---------------------------------
|                                 |
|thing 2                          |
|                                 |
 ---------------------------------
|                                 |
|thing 3                          |
|                                 |
 --------bottom of table----------
```

how do I get it to look like

```
 ---------------------------------
|thing 1                          |
 ---------------------------------
|thing 2                          |
 ---------------------------------
|thing 3                          |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
 --------bottom of table----------
```

or, alternatively like:

```
 ---------------------------------
|thing 1                          |
 ---------------------------------
|thing 2                          |
 ---------------------------------
|thing 3                          |
 --------bottom of table----------





-----bottom of containing div------
```

Comment: try `:last-child` pseudo selector like `tr:last-child`

Comment: would we be able to see your actual code/demo that replicates the spacing issue you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the height of the `tr` to `1px` for all rows but the last.

```css
html, body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;}
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  height:100%;
}
table tr{height:1px;}
table tr:last-child{height:auto;}
table td{vertical-align:top;border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>line 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>line 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>line 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>line 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>line 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>last line</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this line of CSS selector :

```
tr:last-child { height:300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `:last-child` like:

```
tr:last-child
```