# Aligning flexbox item next to flex-grow item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following CSS:

```
.row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.middle {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0 1em;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>X</div>
        <div class="middle">Variable Content</div>
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>X</div>
        <div class="middle">Content</div>
        <div>AB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>X</div>
        <div class="middle">Var Content</div>
        <div>ABC</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This layout which includes rows and three "columns":

- "X" The left column contains the same element in every row, so its width is effectively fixed.  This column should only use the amount of space necessary for the element.
- "Content" The middle column contains variable text.  It should occupy the majority of each row.
- "ABC" The right column is where I'm having trouble.  The content is text and could be 1-5 characters.  I want the characters left aligned across the entire "table".  *Edit:* I don't want to declare a fixed width.

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjEKBW

**In short: How do I get the "A" in every column to be left aligned down the entire layout?**  I'm not married to the HTML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a `table`...I'd suggest you use one or CSS-Tables.

```css
.row {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table-row;
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 .25em;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>X</div>
    <div class="middle">Variable Content</div>
    <div>A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>X</div>
    <div class="middle">Content</div>
    <div>AB</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>X</div>
    <div class="middle">Var Content</div>
    <div>ABC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternatively, you can dispense with the rows and use CSS Grid**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

.grid div {
  padding: 0 .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div>X</div>
  <div class="middle">Variable Content</div>
  <div>A</div>

  <div>X</div>
  <div class="middle">Content</div>
  <div>AB</div>

  <div>X</div>
  <div class="middle">Var Content</div>
  <div>ABC</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the last column a fixed width, e.g.

```css
.row > div:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the column to have a fixed with.  It should only take up as much space as necessary.

Comment: you can convert your html markup to use a `table` instead of `div`s and try this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230953/2766908